# How to stub multiple controls with different IDs?

Tags: sapui5, sinon

Assuming I do have multiple controls with different `ID`s,

```js
let example1 = this.byId("Example1"),
    example2 = this.byId("Example2");
```

Due to the reason that later in the function, `example1` accesses the `.getValueState` and `example2` the `.getValue` method:

```js
if (example1.getValueState() === "Error") { return true; }
if (!example2.getValue()) { return false; }
```

It would require to stub them both. However, when I do that, I do receive the error:

> Attempted to wrap byId which is already wrapped

How do I stub multiple `byId`s?

Comment: sinon added the `stub.onCall(n)` method in v1.8 to allow a stub to return different values per invocation. See: https://sinonjs.org/releases/v14/stubs/#stuboncalln-added-in-v18

Comment: stub.onCall(exampleController, "byId").withArgs("Example1").returns(Example1); stub.onCall(exampleController, "byId").withArgs("Example2").returns(Example2); This way ??

Answer (score 2):

Use `withArgs` to distinguish between the stubs that need to be returned:

```
const oViewStub = sinon.createStubInstance(View);

const oExample1Stub = sinon.createStubInstance(Input);
const oExample2Stub = sinon.createStubInstance(Input);

oViewStub.byId.withArgs("Example1").returns(oExample1Stub);
oViewStub.byId.withArgs("Example2").returns(oExample2Stub);
```